# Possible to Animate GMSMarkers in a GMSPanoramaView

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have added a GMSMarker to a GMSPanoramaView.   While viewing the map I am attempting to update the position property.   However it does not appear to be updating the map to reflect the new position.   Does anybody know if this is possible in the GMSPanoramaView?

For reference we are constructing our markers like this

```
GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:coordinate];
marker.panoramaView = self.panoramaView; //panaroma view is initialized elsewhere
```

and then when we update the position we are simply doing

```
marker.position = newLocation
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how far away the new position is from the current panaroramaview's location, the updated marker might be too small and you won't be able to see it.  Check out the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/streetview#markers_within_street_view).

If that's the case, you could try setting the marker's position to nil to remove it from the panorama view it's attached to, then update the position as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_marker#aa3125bf6fe95369108857467b48e52f7).